# How can I redeem a lost stock certificate?

Tags: stocks, share-certificate

My father had purchased share in the year 1993 but he has lost or misplaced the share certificate he just have share folio no now what should he do to get share money

Comment: Which country is this?

Answer (score 3):

Without any further details (such as country, company name etc.) it's difficult to give you any specific advice.

You should contact the Investor Relations department of the company in question.

Cheers,
Richard.